# C# - Como convertir dato string del teclado a Char?

Tags: c#, array, algoritmos

Buenas comunidad!

Soy nuevo en el Lenguaje C# y estoy haciendo un programa donde se crean 3 fenotipos (osea 3 vectores, cada de tamaño 4) donde 2 son padre y madre, de estos 2 se tiene que generar el hijo (el 3er vector), el usuario tendrá que llenar los vectores manualmente con cualquier letra del abecedario (A-Z o a-z, ya sean mayúsculas o minúsculas) ya que estos representaran los genes y de estos se genera el hijo (teniendo en cuenta que la letra mayúscula son los genes dominantes).

Voy al punto, en cuanto a mi lógica puedo decir que ya se como realizar el programa, el problema es como hago para convertir el dato del teclado (ya se que los datos ingresados del teclado son de tipo Strings) a tipo Char?

En el programa tengo definido los vectores asi:

```
char[] Padre = new char[4];
char[] Madre = new char[4];
char[] Hijo = new char[4];

    void pMH()
    {
        char gen;
        char aux, aux1;
        Console.WriteLine ("Genes del Padre");
        for (int i = 0; i < Padre.Length; i++) 
        {
            Console.Write ("Ingrese gen [" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
            gen = Console.ReadLine();
            Padre [i] = gen;
        }
```

Como pueden ver tengo un`char gen;` donde ahí guarda el dato introducido el teclado, pero me arroja error, obviamente el error es que no se puede guardar un String en un Char, he intentado convertirlo forzosamente osea algo así: `gen = (char)Console.ReadLine();` y no consigo hacerlo.

Por favor, he indagado por google y me salen resultados utilizando el metodo `.ToCharArray();` pero no tengo entendido como funciona, intente implementarlo en mi programa pero no consigo entender ese método y obviamente no funciona.

Espero me puedan ayudar con ese problema, por favor.

Muchas gracias por su atencion, que tengan una Feliz Semana :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método `ToCharArray()` convierte el String en un `Array` de `Chars` , se podría usar dicho método y a su vez acceder a la **`posición 0`** de dicho `Array` que será la primera tecla presionada.

```
gen = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray()[0];
Padre[i] = gen;
```

La otra opción sería empleando el método [Console.ReadKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx) , con un salto de línea adicional , para que no se muestren pegadas las teclas en consola.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Padre.Length; i++)
 {
   Console.Write("Ingrese gen [" + (i + 1) + "]: ");
   gen = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar; /* Obtener el Caracter */
   Console.WriteLine(); /* Salto de Línea adicional */
   Padre[i] = gen;
 }
```

Comment: Hola, le agradezco por haberme respondido. Pues bueno le comento, me acogí mas al segundo que me dejaste, `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`. También me he dado cuenta que se podía mediante el método `System.Console.Convert.ToChar();` y también funciono solo con la diferencia que tengo guardar los datos del teclado en una variable String y luego hacerle la conversión. ¡Solucionado!

Comment: Neither. Perfecto me alegro que haya solucionado por su cuenta un método más. Esa siempre es la forma.

Answer (score 3):

Estrictamente hablando, no es posible convertir una cadena a un carácter, porque las cadenas pueden tener varios caracteres.

Pero si lo que deseas es simplemente obtener el primer carácter de la cadena, esto se puede hacer usando una sintaxis como si la cadena fuera un array. No hay necesidad de usar `.ToCharArray()`, que crea un array adicional innecesario:

```
gen = Console.ReadLine()[0];
```